# insert checkbox value into database via hidden input

Tags: php, html

I have a contact form on my website and in this form I create a check box with span. To insert the checkbox value in the database I use a hidden input but regardless of checking or not checking the checkbox, the value is not saved in database

```js
$('.checkbox').on('click', function(){

   if($(this).find('.figure-container div').hasClass('clicked'))
     {

       $(this).find('.figure-container div').addClass('face').removeClass('entypo-check clicked').animate('slow'); 

     }else{

   $(this).find('.figure-container div').removeClass('face').addClass('entypo-check clicked').animate('slow'); 
    }
});
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <form action="" method="POST" >
<section>
  <div class="wrapper-checkbox">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <div class="figure-container">
        <div class="figure face"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        <span name="check1">rent</span>
        <input type="hidden" name="check1" value="rent">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
          <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src="js-checkbox/index.js"></script>
      </form>

<?php
$check1 = !empty($_POST['check1']) ? $_POST['check1'] : '';
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($connect, "INSERT INTO $db_table VALUES (?)"))
{
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s",$check1);
?>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Where is the code that creates the checkbox and where is the code that copies the value of the checkbox to the hidden field? Can you show index.js ?

Comment: thank you for your answering of course just a moment

Comment: what is being saved on the database now?

Comment: I don't care about the CSS. Please post the JS

Comment: no matter i check the checkbox or not the value here is rent save in database

Comment: I post js in my first post. it is only 2 line and in the middle of the code

Comment: No. You have posted `<script src="js-checkbox/index.js"></script>` that does not tell us anything - post the content of js-checkbox/index.js INSTEAD of the css -  btw here is another of your posts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37795589/insert-span-values-in-database-with-php-prepared-statements

Comment: yes sorry i edit my code

Answer (score 0):

You do not change the input field at all

Your code is far too complex, but something like this is needed (not tested)

```js
$('.checkbox').on('click', function() {
  var value="";
 if ($(this).find('.figure-container div').hasClass('clicked')) {
    $(this).find('.figure-container div').addClass('face').removeClass('entypo-check clicked').animate('slow');
  } else {
    $(this).find('.figure-container div').removeClass('face').addClass('entypo-check clicked').animate('slow');
    value="rent";
  }
  $(this).closest(".wrapper-checkbox").find("input[name=check]").val(value);
});
```

using

```
  <div class="wrapper-checkbox">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <div class="figure-container">
        <div class="figure face"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        <span name="check1">rent</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="check" value="">
  </div>
```

Comment: excuse me span and input names are different is it ok?

Comment: and also input value is empty how about that?

Comment: I have one input field and update that with buy,rent if both divs are checked

Comment: i do not get, it is not two div it is just one div. it is just one checkbox rent. and i want to save it in database if user check it